# Wait until js script is loaded on the page

Tags: javascript, dart

I'm trying to add js file to the page. How to check if that file is loaded?

javascript ga.js file:

```
this.event = function (value) {
    this.value = value;
    this.method = function() {
        return "sometext";
    };
};
```

Dart code:

```
ScriptElement ga = new ScriptElement()
    ..src = "/ga.js"
    ..async = true;
querySelector('body').append(ga);

bool exist = context.hasProperty('event');
    JsObject event = null;
    if (exist) {
        print("event exist");
    } else {
        print("there is no event yet");
    }
```

Comment: you want to know whether the js script is even loaded in your html?

Comment: Yes, @patrick. When it's loaded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just add an `onload` event to any `script` element in HTML.

```
ga.onload = function(ev) { alert('loaded!') };
```

Since this is [native `HTMLScriptElement` behaviour](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLScriptElement#Example_.231.3A_Dynamically_importing_scripts) it should combine fine with Dart.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. With dart I did `ga.onLoad.listen((e) => checkGA());` just for double check and removed Future

Answer (score 1):

The way I found for now it's to use Future.

```
void checkEvent() {
    bool exist = context.hasProperty('event');
    JsObject event = null;
    if (exist) {
        print("event exist");
    } else {
        print("there is no event yet");
        var future = new Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 10), checkEvent);
    }
}
```

But it's if I now already that 'event' exist in that javascript file. Maybe there is some way to check when javascript loaded in html?

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers with Developer tools like Chrome, Firefox, and even IE have a tab called Network. In these panels/tabs you can search for the file in question. If it has loaded it will be in that view.

As long as the JavaScript recognizes/attempts to load the `.js` file, the `console` will usually tell you if it couldn't load the file.

If you're planning on doing something on your page after the file has loaded then you would want to do something more along the lines of what `Niels Keurentjes` suggested.

**More Information:**

[Chrome's Network Panel](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/network#network_panel_overview)

[Firefox's Network Panel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor)

[Internet Explorer's Network Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg130952%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#HOWTO)

[OnLoad Event](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3724571)